# How can I remove the text of a node without removing child nodes?

Tags: php, dom, text, element

I'm working on creating XML docs from values in a database. Initially, the program exports this XML:

```
<customDataElementlanguage>English</customDataElementlanguage>
```

I've created this PHP to change the XML tree:

```
    if ($Element->nodeValue = "EN") { $Element->nodeValue = "English"; }

    $doc2 = $Element->ownerDocument;
    $titleElement = $doc2->createElement('title','language');
    $valueElement = $doc2->createElement('value',$Element->nodeValue);
    $Element->appendChild($titleElement);
    $Element->appendChild($valueElement);
    //$Element->nodeValue="";
```

into this:

```
<customDataElementlanguage>
English
<title>language</title>
<value>English</value>
</customDataElementlanguage>
```

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to remove the "English" text from the node without wiping out the child nodes `title` and `value` inside. That's what happens when I end my PHP code with `$Element->nodeValue="";`

I'd also like to change the name of the customDataElemementlanguage node to customDataElement but I can work on that later I suppose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest would be to store the `nodeValue` in a temporary variable and unset the `nodeValue` *before* creating the other nodes.

```
$lang = $Element->nodeValue;
$Element->nodeValue = "";
$doc2 = $Element->ownerDocument;
$titleElement = $doc2->createElement('title','language');
$valueElement = $doc2->createElement('value', $lang);
$Element->appendChild($titleElement);
$Element->appendChild($valueElement);
```

But you should also be able to remove the `DOMText` node via

```
$Element->removeChild($Element->childNodes->item(0));
```

at the end.

Comment: Thanks very much, nice & simple! Made my day.

Comment: OK now the secondary problem has become a bigger one than I thought ... renameNode() doesn't exist in DOM 2 ("not yet implemented") so I'll start another question with that.